# Why my code has IllegalStateException Error

Tags: java, arraylist

```
package findmiles;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Findmiles {
    private ArrayList<String> city = new ArrayList<String>();
    private long[][] distance;

    public void inputCity() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!in.next().equals("###")) {
           city.add(in.next());
           in.close();
        }
    }
    public void inputDistance() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i, j;
        int n = city.size();
        distance = new long[n][n];
        for (i = 0; i < city.size(); i++)
            for (j = 0; j < city.size(); j++)
                distance[i][j] = in.nextLong();
        in.close();
    }
    public long getDistance(String a, String b) {
        int n = 0, m = 0;
        for (String k : city)
            if (k.equals(a))
                n = city.indexOf(k);
        for (String j : city)
            if (j.equals(b))
                m = city.indexOf(j);
        return distance[n][m];
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Findmiles dis = new Findmiles();
        dis.inputCity();
        dis.inputDistance();
        System.out.println(dis.getDistance(in.next(), in.next()));
        in.close();

    }
}
```

What I want to do is to output 708 when I enter these:

Hagzou  Hugzou  Jigxng    ###
0   1108    708
1108    0   994
708 994 0
Hagzou    Jigxng

It is a program to figure out distance between two cities. First you enter some name of cities, and end with "###". Then enter a matrix of distance, when the names are the same, distance is 0. Then enter two cities's names, and return the distance between them.

Comment: plase print the stack trace

Comment: You do not throw `IllegalStateException` in your program (directly), so we cannot know. Please add stack trace of your exception so we can see where error was thrown. And in general, follow the stack trace to find error on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, After Traversing the Code, i found that you are closing the Scanner which in `inputCity()` inside the loop, you need to move it outside the loop because you are closing it after each iteration which is POSSIBLY give you `IllegalStateException` at second iteration, there should be no problem at first iteration, but at second one it tries to get a value from closed inputstream.

so your code should be

```
public void inputCity() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!in.next().equals("###")) {
            city.add(in.next());
        }
       in.close()
    }
```

for `inputDistance()` method there should be no problem at all (at least with inputstream) because you are closing the input after all loops since if the curly brackets not added then it should take the next one statement **ONLY**